# `torch.round()` is not working as expected

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am running a deep network on GPU so ideally all of my code should work effeciently under GPU (so torch rather than numpy) and I am trying to round the tensor values with `torch.round()` but the result is not expected:

```
testing_value = torch.tensor(3.440000057220459)
torch.round(testing_value, decimals = 2)
```

this output results `tensor(3.4400)`, but shouldn't it be `tensor(3.44)`?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to floating points. You simply can't have exactly the number `3.44` with standard floats. There is nothing to fix here, the number is as close to `3.44` as it's going to get.

Answer (score -1):

This how the code should look like:

```
testing_value = torch.tensor(3.440000057220459)
torch.set_printoptions(precision=2)
torch.round(testing_value, decimals = 2)
```

Output:

```
tensor(3.44)
```